# What happens to a PC lycanthrope's ability scores if it becomes cured?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, ability-scores, lycanthropy

I have a Fighter character who is a lycanthrope and had a very low Strength score originally, but thanks to her lycanthropic affliction, her Strength is now the highest score.

**Will her Strength score increase be removed if she is cured or will it be kept?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The stat change is part of the lycanthrope package

The **Player Characters as Lycanthropes** rules (MM p. 207) state that:

> A character who becomes a lycanthrope retains his or her statistics except as specified by lycanthrope type.

The modifications from the lycanthrope type come as a package. Either you are a lycanthrope and you get those modifications or you aren't and you don't get them. Curing the curse therefore removes all those changes, including stat modifications.